# How to place carried numbers in the French division algorithm with xlop?

Tags: xlop

The French divisional algorithm was taught in the 1960s in primary schools.
It is an algorithm that allows you to quickly perform all divisions. In this algorithm, carried numbers are placed in front of the numbers so that subtractions do not have to be made.
The French algorithm is explained here (in french):

[division à la française](http://www.neoprofs.org/t72128p50-la-division-a-deux-chiffres-ou-plus-cm#4260310)

For example, in the division of 11945 by 47, the first step is to multiply 2×7 = 14, this result must be
removed at 9. It's impossible; you have to put 1
in front of 9 and remove the 14 to 19.
That's five.
Carried number 1 must be added to the result of
the next multiplication.

[image: retenue division]

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}

\begin{document} 

\opidiv{11945}{47}

\end{document}
```

How to place this carried number in front of the numbers with xlop?

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution with `TiKz` that uses the stylization of digits allowed by `xlop` with `operandstyle`, `remainderstyle` parameters.
To do this, I have adapted my given solution to the following question: [Drawing a circle around the numbers in xlop package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388865/138900)

With `xlop`, when the style of a digit is applied by a macro, the last argument (the digit to be stylized) is provided by xlop itself to this macro.

Thus, the macro is declared with 2 arguments, but only the first one is provided to its call, xlop itself providing the last one.

I created two macros:

1. The first macro called `\chiffre` creates a node with TiKz, it has two arguments: first is its name, the second the digit to stylize itself;
2. The second macro called `\retenue` places the carried number at the bottom left of the digit *(as I learned to do myself)*, its first argument is the name of the digit, its second argument is the carried number.

The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\chiffre}[2]{\tikz[remember picture] \node[inner sep=0pt](#1){#2};}
\newcommand{\retenue}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
                          \node[inner sep=0pt,
                                outer sep=2pt,
                                anchor=north east,
                                font=\tiny]at(#1){#2} ;}

\begin{document} 
\opidiv[dividendbridge,
        operandstyle.1.3=\chiffre{a},
        remainderstyle.1.1=\chiffre{b},
        remainderstyle.2.1=\chiffre{c}]{11945}{47}
\retenue{a}{1}
\retenue{b}{4}
\retenue{c}{3}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: retenue division à la française]

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find a solution with `xlop`, but, since nobody answered yet, this is a manual workaround with `tikzmark`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document} 

\tikzmark{mydiv}\opidiv[dividendbridge, columnwidth=1.1em]{11945}{47}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[font=\tiny, shift={(2.3em,8.75ex)}] at (pic cs:mydiv)
    {1};
    \node[draw=red, shift={(2.6em,9ex)}, circle, thick, text width=6pt] at (pic cs:mydiv)
    {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]