# Long divisions in pages

Tags: math-operators

I'm using the 'insert equation' function in pages and there I can type some LaTeX code to get equations and so on. Anyway, **very basic stuff**.
Now, I started using LaTeX a week ago, I found a lot of blogs and websites containing some codes, mathematical operators and stuff like this but what I can't find is how to get long divisions.
At least, I can't find exactly what I need: [long divisions like the ones you see on children books](http://mafaldavocididonne.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/divisione2.gif).
I see a lot of people asked about them but they are completely different from what I need, here are some links I found:
[*noob* LaTeXiT long division](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374754/noob-latexit-long-division)
[Better way to display long division?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131125/better-way-to-display-long-division)
[Long division spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467968/long-division-spacing)
[Displaying the complete Long division](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476518/displaying-the-complete-long-division)
but the problem is they have a different structure... Is there a way to display what I am looking for (using simple code, I'm using pages, I tried using some of the code I found but it doesn't work, I assume that's because I can't download packets) or at least something like that that will work on the 'import equation' thing in pages?

Comment: Welcome between the users of TeX.SE. Therefore do you want have the classic long italian divisions?

Comment: @Sebastiano thanks, yes, please...

Comment: The `xlop` package allows you to do long divisions in the French way.

Comment: @AndréC I'm using pages on mac, I read I can't really download packages...

Comment: @AndréC Great AndréC :-). The same structure are in Italian school. Please, can  you add to the user the link of the package?

Comment: note that long division layout is very country specific, I _never_ saw long division laid out like that as a child (or even at University) only much later.

Comment: This forum is dedicated to the free open source composition system created by Donald Knuth: `TeX` and its derivatives: `LaTeX`, `ConTeXt`, as well as the software designed to work with `Asymptote`, `Metapost`. I'm afraid you have the wrong forum because `pages` is proprietary software.

Comment: @Sebastiano have a look here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/406258/138900 :-)

Comment: @AndréC no, I use LaTeX language but it’s very limited... I don’t know how to explain it, I’ll post a screenshot tomorrow, thanks a lot btw

Comment: @Sebastiano have a look here too: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/277246/138900

Comment: pages does not use tex at all, it converts the tex syntax to mathml using blahtex see https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202501

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, ok I need the syntax to do what I said in my question but I don’t know how to do that